# Sorting by enum and integer in an object in a list in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, enums

I have this class and enum in my program (names changed and simplified):

```
public enum Types {
    FIRST, SECOND, THIRD
}
public class TestClass {
    Types types;
    int num;
    public TestClass(Types types, int num) {
        this.types = types;
        this.num = num;
}
```

Now let's say I have TestClass objects in an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<TestClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new TestClass(Types.THIRD, 2);
list.add(new TestClass(Types.THIRD, 1);
list.add(new TestClass(Types.FIRST, 3);
list.add(new TestClass(Types.FIRST, 1);
list.add(new TestClass(Types.FIRST, 2);
```

I would like to sort the list first based on the enums and then based on the num, so that the end result would be this:

```
[(Types.FIRST, 1), (Types.FIRST, 2), (Types.FIRST, 3), (Types.THIRD, 1), (Types.THIRD, 2)]
```

I see that I could use Comparator, but I'm unsure exactly how I could sort by enums and then by numbers inside the enums. Two comparators? Nested comparators? What would be the optimal solution for this?

Comment: A lot will come down to how re-usable a solution you want (ie, if you have a `Comparator` for the `Types` enum already or not), but basically, if the comparison between `Types` is `0`, then you compare the `int`, but you might need to apply some additional "weighting" to make it work just right

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Java 8?  If so, you can write

```
Comparator<TestClass> comparator = 
   comparing(tc -> tc.types)
      .thenComparingInt(tc -> tc.num);
```

...and then you could write

```
list.sort(comparator);
```

Comment: You might have to add some extra type parameters like this: `Comparator<TestClass> comparator = Comparator.<TestClass, Types>comparing(x -> x.types).thenComparing(x -> x.num)`